# Is it possible to get or set the position of tab-stops (left, center or right ones)?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

(with Google Apps Script Documents)

I can't get positions of the left, center or right tab-stop programmatically (with apps script). Is this possible to set or get positions like indents of paragraph (getIndentFirstLine()) ?

[image]

Comment: I can't find any way to get or set tab stops.

Comment: The Google Docs API is not very full-featured.

Comment: @tehhowch  The value of your contributions here is much greater than your reputation value suggests.  I've come to believe that you must have wrapped around the maximum reputation value and started over again. Perhaps more than once.