# How add left tab-stop to a Paragraph object in a Google Doc with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have searched in [Google Apps Script Reference for Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph) and I couldn't find the correct method to add a left tab-stop to a paragraph object.

In the Google Docs editor, I can do this manually using the context menu on the top ruler.

[image: context menu to add left tab-stop and others]

I expected to find something like this in the reference documentation:

```
const paragraph = body.appendParagraph("Acme Corp.\t$1,000.00");
paragraph.addTabStop(TabStop.LEFT, 3.00);
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be possible in the basic apps script service, but [may be at least partially available in the API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#tabstop) ; it might be possible to use this in apps script [via the advanced service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/docs).See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49836768/is-it-possible-to-get-or-set-the-position-of-tab-stops-left-center-or-right-on).