# How to set Pageless Google Document via Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

Recently Google added this cool feature: [Pageless Docs](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/150905607/google-docs-new-feature-pageless?hl=en).
I would like to activate it on all my documents.

However I cannot find the Property/Method to activate it.
The code should be something like:

```
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.document");

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(file.getUrl());
    var body = doc.getBody();
    // set documet as Pageless ¿?
    doc.saveAndClose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other Google Documents features, like setting tab stops, setting the pageless mode programmatically to a Google Document it's not yet possible. Send a feature request though the Google Apps Script [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191640%2B) and keep an eye to the [Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases).

Related

- [Is it possible to get or set the position of tab-stops (left, center or right ones)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49836768/1595451)

Comment: Thanks @Rubén. I've just created the request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227875469

Comment: Just in case I'm lucky and the Feature is added, I'm not yet marking your answer as accepted ;)